# JSON Serializer tries to access a EntityFramework context that is long gone, for data I did not ask for, or care about

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net

**What am I trying to do?**

I am sending a API call to my C# Backend (MSSQL + EF6),

```
http://localhost:56680/api/Booking/Countries
```

The concern of this API call is to just fetch me the Countries from my DB.

[image: SQL Database Table Structure]

The reason I am including a screenshot from my DB is because Cars is the trouble maker here.

Countries and Cars have a Many2Many relationship with eachother, represented by CountryCars (basically that's Vignettes).

---

These are the corresponding Domain Models:

**Car.cs**

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid GUID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public virtual VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; } 
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public int NrOfSeats { get; set; }
    public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Country> Vignette { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public virtual FuelType FuelType { get; set; }
    public string ReasonOfAbsence { get; set; }
    public bool isForCarSharing { get; set; }
    public int? SharepointId { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
        Location = new Location();
        Equipment = new Equipment();
        FuelType = new FuelType();
        VehicleType = new VehicleType();
        Vignette = new List<Country>();
        Available = true;
    }

    public Car(Car car)
    {
        Id = car.Id;
        GUID = car.GUID;
        Model = car.Model;
        VehicleType = car.VehicleType;
        Location.Name = car.Location.Name;
        LicensePlate = car.LicensePlate;
        NrOfSeats = NrOfSeats;
        Equipment = car.Equipment;
        Vignette = car.Vignette;
        Available = car.Available;
        FuelType.FuelName = car.FuelType.FuelName;
        ReasonOfAbsence = car.ReasonOfAbsence;
    }

}
```

**Country.cs**

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid GUID { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Country()
    {

    }

    public Country(int id, string cc)
    {
        Id = id;
        CountryCode = cc;
    }

    public Country(int id, string cc, string cn)
    {
        Id = id;
        CountryCode = cc;
        CountryName = cn;
    }

    public Country(int id, Guid guid, string countryCode, string countryName)
    {
        Id = id;
        GUID = guid;
        CountryCode = countryCode;
        CountryName = countryName;
    }
}
```

---

**Code & Structure**

API Controller Code:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("Countries")]
    public ICollection<Country> GetCountries()
    {
        try
        {
            return BL.Instance.GetAllCountries();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Getting Countries failed: (" + User.Identity.Name + ") " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

DAO Code:

```
public ICollection<Country> GetAllCountries()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _dbContext = new CarSharingContext())
            {
                return _dbContext.Countries.ToList();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

So, the hand down of that request looks like this:

```
Web -> API Layer -> Business Layer -> Data Access Layer -> EF
```

and comes back like this:

```
Web <- API Layer <- Business Layer <- Data Access Layer <- EF
```

It took me quite a while to understand that at the very last return, when JSON.net serializes my Object to a .json, it suddenly tries to pull this move:

```
       API Layer ----------------------------------------> EF
```

Which baffles me. I wonder why the serializer can't just serialize an empty array / null in that field instead of trying to reach back all the way to a context that's long gone? I realize what it's trying to do, and I see that this is very nice for the sake of having nicely populated objects.

But, in my opinion this shouldn't be the concern of a serializer to start reaching back for more data. This is a call I 100% did not ask for at any point.

Here's the JSON I get returned from the API:

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": null,
"InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Error getting value from 'Cars' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Country_DAAADB66BC9D631592190A398D1C864E889F15DB34CB65EDB14A5FEB021BE73A'.",
    "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
    "StackTrace": "   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   bei System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   bei System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   bei System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   bei System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.ObjectDisposedException",
        "StackTrace": "   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.get_Connection()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Country_DAAADB66BC9D631592190A398D1C864E889F15DB34CB65EDB14A5FEB021BE73A.get_Cars()\r\n   bei GetCars(Object )\r\n   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)"
    }
}
}
```

---

**Stuff I've tried**

I've tried doing .Include(c => c.Cars), but that immediately gives me the CS0311 error, and this is not desirable code anyways.

I've also thought about doing this with DTOs, but I don't really like the idea of cluttering my backend even more with more classes.

I had two other devs looking at this problem baffled as well.

Comment: Have you tried disabling lazyloading? also its not cars which is the problem its country and virtual properties id assume

Comment: also have you tried adding `[JsonIgnore]` the property you dont want. however the common solution to this would be dtos with only the information you need, as leaking this stuff back into your domain is just as ugly

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thank you very much for offering multiple approaches and your experience on the matter. Simply doing `_dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` did the trick. I didn't think it could be that simple. This gives me a json with the data how I want it, plus a Car field that is simply null, which is more than acceptable, since I can just ignore that field. You are probably very right that DTOs would be the cleaner solution here, but since the FrontEnd digests the objects and their structure pretty much 1:1, there is no direct need imo for adding another layer there.

Comment: @MichaelRandall If you would like to put your solution(s) as an answer to this question, I would be more than happy to accept it right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To formalize this into an answer: it seems that the serializer is trying to lazy load the offending collection through the `virtual` properties.

You could try disabling lazying loading on EF for that query. Personally I disable it globally, because it's evil:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false
```

Another solution is ignoring the serialization via `[JsonIgnore]` on the appropriate properties. However, pushing this down to your *Domain Layer* would smell.

Or you could project to DTOs to better encapsulate the data you want and don't want.

Comment: Nitpicking: the most preferable option (DTOs) aside, I'd prefer `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` which ensures that the materialized entities themselves are incapable of lazy loading even when in a theoretical case `LazyLoadingEnabled` is re-enabled on the same context.